# php query doesn't die properly

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm having some trouble getting this query to 'die' properly. I'm using a html form to search for data in a table. now if the data exists the query works perfectly display everything i need it too. but if I know the data doesn't exist using the die in my code I want it to display "Error getting data please search again" but it doesn't. All just does nothing, absolutely nothing! Can you see any errors within the code? I can upload the whole html file if need be. I've been looking at it for hours and starting to go a bit mad! Thanks

```
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

    $category = $_POST ['category'];
    $criteria = $_POST ['criteria'];

    $query = "SELECT g.GameID, g.GameName, g.PubID, g.TimePeriodID, g.SettingID, g.MoodID, g.GameWeaponID, g.GameCameraAngleID, g.GamePlayerTypeID, g.GameDescription FROM GameTable g WHERE $category = '$criteria'";  //selecting all the data from the game table that makes the search criteria
    $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query) or die("Error getting data please search again");

    echo "<table class='col-md-12'>"; // displays the searched data as a table


    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        echo "<form class=col-md-6 action=searchgame.php method=post>";
        echo "<tr> <th> Game ID</th> </tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input class=text-black type=text name=gameid readonly=readonly value=" . $row['GameID'] . " </td> <br>"; //here i have made the game Id read only so that it is not editable by the administrator
        echo "<tr> <th> Game Name</th> </tr>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input class=text-black type=text name=gamename value=" .$row['GameName'] . " < /td> <br>"; // editable boxes so administator can update
        echo "<tr> <th> Publisher ID</th> </tr>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input class=text-black type=text name=pubid value=" . $row['PubID'] . " < /td><br>";
        echo "<tr> <th> Time Period ID</th> </tr>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input class=text-black type=text name=timeperiodid value=" . $row['TimePeriodID'] . " < /td><br>";
        echo "<tr> <th> Setting ID</th> </tr>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input class=text-black type=text name=settingid value=" . $row['SettingID'] . " < /td> <br>"; 
        echo "<tr> <th> Mood ID</th> </tr>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input class=text-black type=text name=moodid value=" . $row['MoodID'] . " < /td><br>";
        echo "<tr> <th> Weapon ID</th> </tr>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input class=text-black type=text name=gameweaponid value=" . $row['GameWeaponID'] . " < /td><br>";
        echo "<tr> <th> Camera Angle ID</th> </tr>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input class=text-black type=text name=gamecameraangleid value=" . $row['GameCameraAngleID'] . " < /td><br>";
        echo "<tr> <th> Player ID</th> </tr>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input class=text-black type=text name=gameplayertype value=" . $row['GamePlayerTypeID'] . " < /td><br>";
        echo "<tr> <th> Game Description</th> </tr>";
        echo "<td>" . "<textarea style=height:200px;width:300px; class=text-black type=text name=gamedescription value=>" . $row['GameDescription'] . "</textarea><br>";
        echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $row['GameID'] . " </td>";

        echo "<td>" . "<input class=text-black input-button-rounded type=submit name=update value=Update" . " </td>"; //update button 
        echo "<td>" . "<input class=text-black input-button-rounded type=submit name=delete value=Delete" . " </td>"; //delete button
        echo "</tr>";
        echo"</form>";

    }

    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Then get the real error `mysqli_error($dbcon)`

Comment: also print the query and run in mysql directly...

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 3):

This is the key part to your question

> but if I know the data doesn't exist

The reason die doesn't do anything is the query completes perfectly fine, just with no results.

try this instead

```
  if( !$result->num_rows )  die('please search again');
```

There is no `error` per say, only an empty result set.  Using the property of the result set `num_rows` will tell you the number of rows that match the search.  In the case of `0` PHP treats this as `false` or `!` for short hand.

Die is only executed if the method in front of it returns false, which as you return the result set object from mysqli, that's not the case.

A lot of people miss-understand what this does, or just don't know

```
     $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query) or die("Error getting data please search again");
```

this is roughly equivalent to this

```
       if( ($result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query)) || die("Error getting data please search again"));
```

We just skip over the if, the `or` is a logical operator you can use in an if statement just fine.  The only difference with using `OR` or `||` is the precedence in when they are evaluated ( or so I read some where). I've never in 7 years put `OR` in an if statement ... lol

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp

```
       if( ($result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query)) OR die("Error getting data please search again"));
```

So all that said if the first condition is true in the statement, because of the OR there is no need to check the second statement. That's all it does.

Comment: I may not have grasped the question fully. You may very well be right but I interpreted it in a different way. I posted a comment under my answer. If this is the solution, great! I'm all for it and I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Yea it took me a few reads though to figure that out.  I am pretty sure they just want the die command to run if the results are empty.

Comment: Thank you, makes total sense now that i think about it! Now working successfully!

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Same here. When I saw the other answer (now delete) and noticed they basically added the error trigger with the connection, since the OP wasn't checking for the real error (had there been one), I almost commented under it saying that that was basically what I wrote in a comment under the OP's question.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix However, I must admit that my answer was technically correct, just not the solution the OP was looking for. lol Gladly upvoted yours, if I may permit myself to say.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  Thanks!, the only part that tipped me off was this `but if I know the data doesn't exist` that's why I included it in the answer.  Otherwise I was scratching my head for a minute, then I went ... Oh hold on.. lol

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Haha! so true, yet that was the part I had trouble deciphering (completely). You were the "Top Dog Code Detective" ;-) *Cheers* and good job and you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

> *"I'm having some trouble getting this query to 'die' properly. I'm using a html form to search for data in a table. now if the data exists the query works perfectly display everything i need it too. but if I know the data doesn't exist using the die in my code I want it to display "Error getting data please search again" but it doesn't. All just does nothing, absolutely nothing!"*

After reading the question over a few more times, have come to the conclusion that what you need is an `else {...}` statement for the `if{...}`.

> *"Can you see any errors within the code?"*

A: No. You just need to use an `else{...}`.

However, if ever your query should fail you at any given time, you should check for the real error using `mysqli_error()`.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

**Edit:**

I do need to state that your code is open to an SQL injection.

Use a prepared statement.

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

and on PHP.net:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: That's what I got from the question. If I'm wrong about this or I misinterpreted the question, let me know and I'll delete it.

Comment: Well, I was technically correct, just not the solution the OP was looking for. ArtisticPhoenix's was the actual solution.